# Condition in AppleScript if directory doesn't contain extension recursively then quit app

Tags: applescript

This seems to work. The only problem is it is not recursive.

```
property Location : alias "Macintosh HD:Location"
tell application "System Events" to files of Location whose name extension = "ext"
if the result = {} then tell application "Example" to quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entire contents with Finder:

```
set f to POSIX file "/Users/username/folder" as alias
tell application "Finder"
    files of entire contents of f where name extension is "torrent"
end tell
```

If the folder has many files, using find is probably faster:

```
do shell script "find ~/folder -name \\*.torrent" is not ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set downloadsPath to (path to downloads folder)
tell application "System Events" to files of downloadsPath whose name extension = "torrent"
if the result ≠ {} then tell application "Transmission" to activate
```